# Change column names that start with 'C' letter using sql?

Tags: sql, sqlite, ddl, alter-table

Assuming I have this table:
[image]

What I want to do is change all column names that starts with letter `C` to another letter or another word.
I'm not very good in SQL, I have ability to do this using program languages like Java or any other. 
But my purpose is using only SQL.

Is it possible?

Comment: For that you need to access the metadata for the table, and that is outside the SQL standard, so it differs between database vendors. What brand of database are you using?

Comment: @Guffa assume that I'm using sqlite.

Comment: Do you want to do that permanently or just for a single query?

Comment: I am not sure about this but you can change the column headers(used in your code) with programming, not actual column names. you need to access the meta data for this as @guffa told. and the logic/query would be same in programming language and sql if you are doing this in you code using meta data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I didn't understand your comment, sorry can you explain ?

Comment: @Azad just for information, if you have some code in you application like "if(column header == "C1") { do this }" then it won't work again as you changed the column name in DB. I had faced such problem.

Comment: Do you want a `select` query that simply changes the names that are displayed? Or do you want to **permanently** change the names of the columns in the table. So that in the future you would have to use e.g. `foobar` instead of `C1`? And a `select *` would show the new names.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I want **permanently** change it.

Comment: I don't think SQLite allows renaming of columns - at least the manual doesn't show any option for that: http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop and recreate the table.

So:

1)Create a temp table with all the data and structure of the original table. This allows you to drop the original, then recreate it using the same name.

```
Create Table temp as select * from [Table_Name]
```

2)Drop the original table.

```
Drop table [Table_Name]
```

3)Create the new table, with the new column names.

```
Create Table Table_Name
   (Name varchar(20),
    Age int,
    [New_C1] int,
    [New_C2] int),
    [New_C3] int),
   )
```

4)Insert the data from the temp table into the new table:

```
Insert into Table_Name (Name, Age, New_C1, New_C2, New_C3)
Select (Name, Age, C1, C2, C3) FROM temp
```

5)Drop the temp table:

```
Drop table temp
```

**Note**

- I highly recommend wrapping this in a transaction, that way you can rollback.

Comment: That's not the answer that I want, how about if I have 100 column names that start with letter `C`? how about 1000 ? You choose a hard way to do that, I want more general way. The example I wrote is just an assumption. Thanks for yoru answe anyway.

Comment: There isn't another way to do what you want. Have you read the SQlite documentation? The Alter Table statement does not provide you with a way of renaming columns. If you have 100 columns, I'd ask you why you named your columns incorrectly in the first place.